# Fast search algorithm with std::vector<std::string>

Tags: c++, search, vector

```
    for (std::vector<const std::string>::const_iterator it = serverList.begin(); it != serverList.end(); it++)
    {
        // found a match, store the location
        if (index == *it) // index is a string
        {
            indexResult.push_back(std::distance(serverList.begin(), it)); // std::vector<unsigned int>
        }
    }
```

I Have written the above code to look through a vector of strings and return another vector with the location of any "hits".

Is there a way to do the same, but faster? (If I have 10,000 items in the container, it will take a while).
Please note that I have to check ALL of the items for matches and store its position in the container.

Bonus Kudos: Anyone know any way/links on how I can make the search so that it finds partial results (Example: search for "coolro" and store the location of variable "coolroomhere")

Comment: Instead of `i`, say `std::distance(serverList.begin(), it)`; or just access the vector by index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, you're asking if it's possible to check all elements for a
match, without checking all elements.  If there is some sort of external
meta-information (e.g. the data is sorted), it might be possible (e.g.
using binary search).  Otherwise, by its very nature, to check all
elements, you have to check all elements.

If you're going to do many such searches on the list and the list
doesn't vary, you might consider calculating a second table with a good
hash code of the entries; again depending on the type of data being
looked up, it could be more efficient to calculate the hash code of the
index, and compare hash codes first, only comparing the strings if the
hash codes were equal.  Whether this is an improvement or not largely
depends on the size of the table and the type of data in it.  You might
also, be able to leverage off knowledge about the data in the strings; if
they are all URL's, for example, mostly starting with `"http://www."`,
starting the comparison at the tenth character, and only coming back to
compare the first 10 if all of the rest are equal, could end up with a big
win.

With regards to finding substrings, you can use `std::search` for each
element:

```
for ( auto iter = serverList.begin();
        iter != serverList.end();
        ++ iter ) {
    if ( std::search( iter->begin(), iter->end(),
                      index.begin(), index.end() ) != iter->end() ) {
        indexResult.push_back( iter - serverList.begin() );
    }
}
```

Depending on the number of elements being searched and the lengths of
the strings involved, it might be more efficient to use something like
BM search, however, precompiling the search string to the necessary
tables before entering the loop.

Answer (score 9):

Use binary_search after sorting the vector

1. std::sort( serverList.begin() , serverList.end() )
2. std::lower_bound(serverList.begin() , serverList.end() , valuetoFind) to find first matching
3. Use **std::equal_range** if you want to find all matching elements

The **lower_bound  & equal_range** search because it is binary is logarithmic compared to your search that is O(N)

Comment: If the data structure itself is amenable to redesign, an `unordered_multiset<string>` might even be more appropriate.

Comment: My inclination on things I will want sorted is to just add them in sorted in the first place.

Comment: Of course this will only pay if he needs to do it more often, as it is O(nlogn) and his current approach is only O(n).

Comment: @ChristianRau - ...or if you are inclined to trade startup time for runtime.

Answer (score 2):

If you make the container a `std::map` instead of a `std::vector`, the underlying data structure used will be one that is optimized for doing keyword searches like this.

If you instead use a `std::multimap`, the member function [equal_range()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/equal_range/) will return a pair of iterators covering every match in the map. That sounds to me like what you want.

A smart commenter below points out that if you don't actually store any more infomation than the name (the search key), then you should probably instead use a `std::multiset`.

Comment: Since he doesn't store anything else in there, a `std::multiset` would even be better.